# Help to quick start NSS

Tags: java, security, mozilla, nss

I am starting into NSS and I managed to build it. The outcome was placed in a folder named `dist` and has several subfolders that contain several exe's dlls etc.

```
dist  
    /WINNT6.0_DBG.OBJ  
         /bin  
         /include  
         /lib
```

I am trying to try it but I am not sure what is the `nssLibraryDirectory` and `nssSecmodDirectory`   .

For the `nssLibraryDirectory` should I copy everything in the `dist` in a single file and refer to it from `nssLibraryDirectory`?  What about `nssSecmodDirectory`?  I'm not sure how I am suppose to configure to start using sun's pkcs11.

For example this trivial:

```
String configName = "nss.cfg";
Provider p = new sun.security.pkcs11.SunPKCS11(configName );
```

Where nss.cfg is:

```
 name = NSS  
 nssLibraryDirectory = E:\NSS\nss-3.12.4-with-nspr-4.8\mozilla\dist\WINNT6.0_DBG.OBJ\lib 
 nssDbMode = noDb
```

Gives exception

> Caused by: java.io.IOException: The
>   specified module could not be found.
>     at
>   sun.security.pkcs11.Secmod.nssLoadLibrary(Native
>   Method)

Comment: Why is the title 'jss' and the content 'NSS'?  Have you tried 'make dist' or its equivalent?  Have you looked at this [NSS](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/p11guide.html) page at Oracle's web site?

Comment: @Jonathan:Network Security Services for Java (https://developer.mozilla.org/En/JSS).Yes I build dist.Now I can not figure how to configure pkcs11.If I put `E:\NSS\nss-3.12.4-with-nspr-4.8\mozilla\dist\WINNT6.0_DBG.OBJ` I get `nss3.dll File not found` exception.If I place `E:\NSS\nss-3.12.4-with-nspr-4.8\mozilla\dist\WINNT6.0_DBG.OBJ\lib` I get `sun.security.pkcs11.Secmod.nssLoadLibrary(Native Method)` exception

Answer (score 0):

nssLibraryDirectory should only contain the lib subdirectory.
Its also has to appear in PATH - either by modifying environment variable or specifying it in JVM parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Some note from my hard trying.... I think it would help anyone who want to use NSS.

I tend to construct a `String` in Java code to know in which line the error occurs. I must say it's better because Eclipse can eliminate all String construction errors. Then you pay attention to values to fill in.

I use these code:

```
String config = "xxxxxxx" +
                "xxxxxxx" +
                "xxxxxxx" +
                "\n";
provider = new SunPKCS11(new ByteArrayInputStream(config.getBytes()));
Security.insertProviderAt(provider, 1);
```

All flags for Provider config:
(from http://j7a.ru/_config_8java_source.html,
seems like openjdk 8 `sun.security.pkcs11.Config.java`.)

```
name=xxxxxx       //some text, " must be escaped with \
library=/location/of/your/.so/or/.dll/file //not compatible with NSS mode, must be quoted if contains space, and if quoted, " must be escaped
description=
slot=             //not compatible with NSS mode
slotListIndex=    //not compatible with NSS mode
enableMechanisms=
disableMechanisms=
attributes=
handleStartupErrors=
insertionCheckInterval=
showInfo=true/false
keyStoreCompatibilityMode=
explicitCancel=
omitInitialize=
allowSingleThreadedModules=
functionList=
nssUseSecmod=true/false  //not campatible with 'library'
nssLibraryDirectory=     //not campatible with 'library'
nssSecmodDirectory=      //not campatible with 'library'
nssModule=some text      //not campatible with 'library'
nssDbMode=readWrite, readOnly, noDb   //not campatible with 'library'
nssNetscapeDbWorkaround=true/false    //not campatible with 'library'
nssArgs="name1='value1' name2='value2' name3='value3' ... "          //not compatible with NSS mode
nssUseSecmodTrust=true/false
```

Examples of `nssArgs=`: (separated by space)

```
"nssArgs=\"configdir='" + NSS_JSS_Utils.getFireFoxProfilePath() + "' "
+ "certPrefix='' "                          
+ "keyPrefix='' "
+ "secmod='secmod.db' "
+ "flags='readOnly'\""
```

Some example of escaping in Java code:

```
String config = "name=\"NSS Module\"\n" +
                "......" +
                "\n";
```

If with space, must be quoted with `" "`. `' '` is not able to be used. Every `"` must be escaped with `\`.

Now, some real examples.

To use Firefox security modules via NSS:

```
String config = "name=\"NSS Module\"\n"
+ "attributes=compatibility\n"
+ "showInfo=true\n"
+ "allowSingleThreadedModules=true\n"
+ "nssLibraryDirectory=" + NSS_JSS_Utils.NSS_LIB_DIR + "\n"
+ "nssUseSecmod=true\n"
+ "nssSecmodDirectory=" + NSS_JSS_Utils.getFireFoxProfilePath();
```

To use `libsoftokn3.so` (I don't know what it's used for, but I see someone have used it like this with `nssArgs`):

```
String config = "library=" + NSS_JSS_Utils.NSS_LIB_DIR + "/libsoftokn3.so" + "\n"
    + "name=\"Soft Token\"\n";
    + "slot=2\n"
    + "attributes=compatibility\n"
    + "allowSingleThreadedModules=true\n"
    + "showInfo=true\n"
    + "nssArgs=\"configdir='" + NSS_JSS_Utils.getFireFoxProfilePath() + "' "
                + "certPrefix='' "
                + "keyPrefix='' "
                + "secmod='secmod.db' "
                + "flags='readOnly'\""
    + "\n";
```

`NSS_JSS_Utils.NSS_LIB_DIR` returns the directory where all the NSS library libs are. Sometimes they are installed by default(e.g., in my RedHat 7.2), but sometimes you must install them manually.

`NSS_JSS_Utils.getFireFoxProfilePath()` returns where **your FireFox profile** are located. If you use `modutil` shipped with NSS/NSPR, you can see your installed security modules are stored in the `secmod.db` in this folder. If you cannot find them, you may have taken the wrong file.

More info about how to fill these values:

[NSS PKCS#11 Spec](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/NSS/PKCS11/Module_Specs)